# File root problems when moving site from localhost to remote host

Tags: php

1. The site works perfectly fine on localhost however in some files I had to use the full file path name such as `c:/xampp/htdocs/websitename/...`
2. I've tried using the SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'config/config.php thinking this would be the best way to resolve my problem but that did not work either.
3. Any advice on a better approach or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
$path = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/config/config.php';
```

or:

```
$path = __DIR__ . '/config/config.php';
```

to be more platform-/server-independent.

Comment: $path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/";
$path= $path . "config/config.php";
require_once($path);
ive tried this.  To be more specific it seems like I can't get the full directory it ends at /home

Comment: i get this.  is there any way to go deeper into the file root or does cuccfree.com block you from going 
/home/vol10_3/cuccfree.com/